# What's the current Vaadin LTS version?

Tags: vaadin

My project has a bug. It currently uses v18.0.3. When I asked a question in another thread someone mentioned that I should better upgrade to v21, since that's an LTS version. I also recall having received news letters stating that v21 is supposed to be an LTS version.

If I looked at the Vaadin Roadmap (https://vaadin.com/roadmap) today there is no word that v21 is an LTS-version.

Rather v14 is mentioned as last LTS and v23 is apparently to become the next LTS version.
Have plans changed?

Comment: If the documentation says that 14 is the LTS, 14 is the LTS.

Comment: And it says 23 will be the next, then chances are very high it will be that way. If our answers are not enough for you, contact the developers...

Comment: Whoever said that version 21 is an LTS release was mistaken. I don't see your question on StackOverflow or Discord. If you still need help, you should join the [Discord server](https://vaad.in/chat).

Comment: @Oliver Without the point of time, the statement "21 is the next LTS" could as well been correct and OP might think of an old post somewhere. The shift from 21 to 23 was done around 20 (afair) and since no one here was able to produce a link yet, I'd assume not overly loud communicated.  On the other hand there are still references, that at least imply 21 (e.g. 21 can be extrapolated in [the last text block in the 19 announcement](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-19-has-landed-heres-everything-you-need-to-know)

Answer (score 5):

The most recent versions can be found here https://vaadin.com/releases

you'll see that 14 is the current LTS

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely update from 18 to 21 even if 21 isn't an LTS version, because 18 is no longer supported. It'll also potentially make your update easier when the next LTS, 23, is released. With non-LTS versions, you should always update to the latest major to stay on a maintained version.